# VBScript Datepart Weekday displayed incorrect

Tags: date, datetime, vbscript

I can't get the code to display the correct date.

```
DatePart("w", Now()) & _
```

The code is shown as Friday, though where I live it is Thursday. How do I change it -1 day?

I was linked this website by a great guy! Visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kt42529(v=vs.84).aspx But it didn't understand the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either

```
DatePart("w", Now(), vbMonday)
```

or (better as portable anywhere, location independent)

```
DatePart("w", Now(), vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
```

**Explanation**:

`DatePart` Function returns the specified part of a given date.

```
DatePart(interval, date[, firstdayofweek[, firstweekofyear]])
```

*Arguments*:

- `interval` Required. String expression that is the interval of time you want to return. See Settings section for values.
- `date` Required. Date expression you want to evaluate.
- `firstdayofweek` Optional. Constant that specifies the day of the week. **If not specified, Sunday** is assumed.
- `firstweekofyear` Optional. Constant that specifies the first week of the year. If not specified, the first week is assumed to be the week in which January 1 occurs.

FYI: the `firstdayofweek` argument can have the following values:

```
Constant          Value Description 

vbUseSystemDayOfWeek  0 Use National Language Support (NLS) API setting.
vbSunday              1 Sunday (default)
vbMonday              2 Monday
vbTuesday             3 Tuesday
vbWednesday           4 Wednesday
vbThursday            5 Thursday
vbFriday              6 Friday
vbSaturday            7 Saturday
```

The `firstweekofyear` argument can have the following values:

```
Constant    Value Description 

vbUseSystem     0 Use National Language Support (NLS) API setting.
vbFirstJan1     1 Start with the week in which January 1 occurs (default).
vbFirstFourDays 2 Start with the week that has at least four days in the new year.
vbFirstFullWeek 3 Start with the first full week of the new year.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DatePart("w", DateAdd("d",-1,Now()))
```